# visual studio 2015 enterprise update 3 installing error core feature

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation

i want to installing vs 2015 update 3 but i cant its installing give error

Visual Studio Core Features : Fatal error during installation.

setup failed
install cannot continue because some required components failed.

i do some way to solve this problem but not work

1.uninstalling all ms programs like vs 2013 & vs 2012 & sqlserver

2.update my windows(7)

3.clean temp

4.clean C:\ProgramData\Package Cache

5.run as adminstrator installer

6.download again vs2015 enterprise up3

but Still i cant installing vs and its give error
plz help me

log file http://pastebin.com/ywqFXgTQ

Answer (score 0):

The error code “0x80070643” often means the installer is corrupted, have you tried to verify the integrity of the ISO file? From log, it looks like the installer tried to install kb3022398.msp and get this error code, please have a try with repair VS under Control Panel.

Since your OS is Windows 7, make sure SP1 is be installed, the VS is supported on Windows 7 SP1. Before installation, remember to disable your anti-virus software, please check here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/40dbe1d2-062c-455d-8382-4dd384fe2e34/a-setup-package-is-either-missing-or-damaged-vs-2015-community?forum=vssetup

Comment: my os is windows service pack 1

Comment: Have you tried a complete uninstall and reinstall using a healthy ISO file of VS enterprise 2015 without updates from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=48143

Answer (score 0):

and id do some more thing for solve this problem

7.turn off all anti-virus software and windows defender

8. repair VS from control panel Programs and Features but give same error

9.change default instalation location(path)

10. try to install with custom part

but give same error

and i download .netframework 3.5 but i cant install it
i didnt find .netframework 3.5 in control panel Programs and Features
for reinstall it
but it exist in control panel Programs and Features
i do re enable it

i dont know what to do؟ and how solve this problem